# How to create high performance SQL select query, if I need a condition for referrer table's records?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, query-performance

For example, I have 2 tables, which I need for my query, `Property` and `Move` for history of moving properties.

[image: Property]

[image: Move]

I must create a query which will return all properties + 1 additional boolean column, `IsInService`, which will have value `true`, in cases, when `Move` table has a record for property with `DateTo = null` and `MoveTypeID = 1` ("In service").

I have created this query:

```
SELECT  
    [ID], [Name], 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM [Move]
     WHERE PropertyID = p.ID 
       AND DateTo IS NULL 
       AND MoveTypeID = 1) AS IsInService
FROM 
    [Property] as p
ORDER BY 
    [Name] ASC
OFFSET 100500 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY;
```

I'm not so strong in SQL, but as I know, subqueries are the evil :)

How to create high performance SQL query in my case, if it is expected that these tables will include millions of records?

Comment: Use a join instead and see how that performs.

Comment: I don't know which of joins and how exactly I must use to get result which I need

Comment: Something like: `select ID, Name, Count(*) as IsInService from Property p join Move m on p.ID = m.PropertyID where m.DateTo is null and m.MoveTypeID = 1 order by [Name] ASC OFFSET 100500 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY;`

Comment: Perhaps you would do better with [`exists`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189259%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), e.g.: `case when exists ( select 42 from ... ) then 1 else 0 end as IsInService`.

Comment: @CodingYoshi It doesn't work

Comment: @HABO It still use subquery, but thanks for it modernization

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the code based on your comment. If you need something else, please provide input and output data expected. This is about all I can do based on inference from the existing comments. Further, this isn't intended to give you an exact working solution. My intention was to give you a prototype from which you can build your solution.

That said:

The code below is the basic join that you need. However, **keep in mind that indexing is probably going to play as big a part in performance as the structure of the table and the query. It doesn't matter how you query the tables if the indexes aren't there to support the queries once you reach a certain size. There are a lot of resources online for indexing but viewing querying plans should be at the top of your list.**

As a note, your column [dbo].[Property] ([Name]) should probably be NVARCHAR to allow SQL to minimize data storage. Indexes on that column will then be smaller and searches/updates faster.

```
DECLARE @Property AS TABLE
  (
       [ID]     INT
       , [Name] NVARCHAR(100)
  );

INSERT INTO @Property
            ([ID]
             , [Name])
VALUES      (1,N'A'),
            (2,N'B'),
            (3,N'C');

DECLARE @Move AS TABLE
  (
       [ID]           INT
       , [DateTo]     DATE
       , [MoveTypeID] INT
       , [PropertyID] INT
  );

INSERT INTO @Move
            ([ID]
             , [DateTo]
             , [MoveTypeID]
             , [PropertyID])
VALUES      (1,NULL,1,1),
            (2,NULL,1,2),
            (3,N'2017-12-07',1,2);

SELECT [Property].[ID]     AS [property_id]
       , [Property].[Name] AS [property_name]
       , CASE
             WHEN [Move].[DateTo] IS NULL
                  AND [Move].[MoveTypeID] = 1 THEN
                 N'true'
             ELSE
                 N'false'
         END               AS [in_service]
FROM   @Property AS [Property]
       LEFT JOIN @Move AS [Move]
              ON [Move].[PropertyID] = [Property].[ID]
WHERE  [Move].[DateTo] IS NULL
       AND [Move].[MoveTypeID] = 1;
```

Comment: If you'll add second move for some property, you'll see, that result contains 2 rows for this property. But I need just list of properties with flags "IsInService"